# Search for pattern containing decimal using regular expressions in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following data in my notepad++ file:

```
aa(40)

aa(50)

aa(4)

aa(8)

aa(40)
```

How do I search for it using regular expressions in notepad++?

---

**Note** : `aa` is always constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++:

1. Go to Search >> Find
2. Select Regular Expressions
3. Enter following regex: `^aa\(\d+\)`
4. Find All in All Opened Documents

[image]